# creating alias in bash

Tags: bash

Currently this is what I need to type to execute my task

```
execute 'mytask'
```

I want an alias so that I need to type

```
e mytask
```

This is what I did which is not working

```
alias e="execute '$1'"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your alias: `alias e=execute`

As an example, I have `ls` aliased to `l`. I can still type `l -l` and it works as expected.

Any args just get passed through.

Answer (score 3):

Just make it function.

```
e() { execute "$1"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Exposing and hiding quotation marks, is kinda dangerous in bash terms. In case you're willing not to hide the quotation, you can use:

```
alias e="execute"
```

And then use `e 'mytask'`

Answer (score 0):

Is it an absolute must to have it as an alias?

If you're using a .bashrc or .bash_profile you could throw a one-line function in there, like so:

```
e () { execute '$1'; }
```

[ed] Beat'd by a mile! :P